# stripe popup form for credit card issue in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I am using stripe for credit card payments. I was working fine but suddenly it stop working. when user click on pay with card button it should show a popup for card details but it submit form instead of showing popup.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/cart/strip_payment" method="POST">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
    class="stripe-button" 
    data-key="" 
    data-image="" 
    data-name="mydomain.com" 
    data-description="Demo Transaction"
    data-amount="2000" />
    </script>
</form>

require_once APPPATH.'third_party/Stripe/lib/Stripe.php';
Stripe::setApiKey(""); //Replace with your Secret Key

$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 2000,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    "description" => "Demo Transaction"
));
```

but its not giving a popup to user for credit card it always submit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the `<script>` tag twice, once by appending `/>` at the end of the opening tag and once by adding a closing `</script>` tag.

You should change your code like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/cart/strip_payment" method="POST">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
    class="stripe-button" 
    data-key="" 
    data-image="" 
    data-name="mydomain.com" 
    data-description="Demo Transaction"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

You should also check the resulting HTML code from your browser to make sure that the `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` bit is outputting an URL correctly and does not mess with the HTML.